# Detect mouseListener events on JLabel inside JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, jlabel

I have a JTable, inside table cells I added some JLabels.
Is there a way to detect mouse events on these JLabels? 
I tried to add a mouseListener on labels, but it's not invoked and also I think labels don't get focus after a click.

So my question is: is there a way to detect these events on Swing components inside JTable cells?

Comment: Please show your code in form of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: No, not really or at least not without a great deal of difficulty, you're better of monitoring the table or use a cell editor

Comment: The idea was to add 6 labels in each table cell and eventually set a background to the specific label that listens the mouse event. A cell editor could be useful for this purpose?

Comment: I found this "As I found there is no way to add direct listner to components inside JTable. You have to go with JTable's listener only." It's better for me to find a new solution!